# Connecting to Dynamics CRM configured with IFD without using the SDK

Tags: .net-3.5, dynamics-crm-2011, adfs2.0

We have recently configured our Dynamics CRM to use ADFS for IFD.  We are trying to connect to it from .Net 3.5, so we cannot use the CRM SDK.  Below is the code we were using before configuring IFD, and it was working fine.

```
HttpsTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();              
httpTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
httpTransport.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
httpTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

SecurityBindingElement securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateSspiNegotiationBindingElement(true);

TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
textMessageEncoding.MaxReadPoolSize = 64;
textMessageEncoding.MaxWritePoolSize = 16;
textMessageEncoding.WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, textMessageEncoding, httpTransport);
customBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);
customBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);
customBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);

string remoteAddress = String.Empty;


remoteAddress = "https://" + ServiceUri + "/OrgName/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc";

ChannelFactory<IOrganizationService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IOrganizationService>(customBinding, remoteAddress);

ClientCredentials loginCredentials = factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(loginCredentials);

// step two - instantiate your credentials
loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
loginCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain);
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials);

IEnumerable<OperationDescription> operations = factory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations;


foreach (OperationDescription operation in operations)
{
    DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcsob = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
    if (dcsob == null)
    {
        dcsob = new DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operation);
    }
    operation.Behaviors.Remove(dcsob);
    dcsob.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 1012 * 1024 * 1024;
    operation.Behaviors.Add(dcsob);
}


_orgProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Now when we try to connect to the CRM with this code it's returning the following error:
    `</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>`

My question is what additional security headers do I need, and how do I modify the bindings to include them?

Comment: If you want to see how Microsoft does it look at this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/11/02/building-clients-for-windows-phone-and-windows-8-rt.aspx and download the source http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/A/A/1AA59217-D571-4E65-B037-FE59DD945A13/CRMSLSample.zip. It was posted for people to use in building Windows 8 Phone and RT Apps (which didn't support .NET 4 and WIF) but could also be used for a .NET 3.5 project (which can't use .NET 4 DLLs)

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying that the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.
To make the client configuration generated automatically, you can use Add Service Reference option, or use SvcUtil.exe to generate a proxy class.